# SIGSEGV Segmentation Fault at strcmp() on a forked() child process

Tags: c, csv, sorting, fork, parent-child

So I am writing a program that iterates through each file/folder in a directory, and for every CSV file it encounters it will fork() and then sort it and output the CSV file.

The sorting happens in beginSort() which runs mergesort on the CSV and then outputs.

Here's the problem...when I run beginSort() on the default main parent process it works totally as expected. However, when it is being run from a forked() child process, the code fails immediately after this line 170:

```
fgets(titleRow.rowValue, 999, fp);
```

I can't make sense of what is happening. When I set a breakpoint before this line...GDB still just runs right through it and I can't can get meaningful information. Here is the full sorter.c file:

```
#include "Sorter.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <dirent.h>


int isString(char* string) {

    int i = 0;
    int decimal = 0;

    // empty string
    if(string == NULL || string == ""){
        return 1;
    }

    // goes character by character to check if its a number or string
    while(i < strlen(string)){

        if( !isdigit(string[i])){
            if(string[i] == '.' && !decimal){
                if(i == strlen(string) - 1 || !isdigit(string[i + 1])){
                    return 1;
                }
                decimal = 1;
                i++;
                continue;
            }
            return 1;
        }
        i++;
    }
    return 0;
}

// trims trailing and leading blank spaces in a string
char* removeWhitespace(char *string, int i) {

  char *final;

  while(isspace((unsigned char)*string)){
    string++;
  }

  if(*string == 0) {
    return string;
  }
  final = string + i;
  while(final > string && isspace((unsigned char)*final)) {
      final--;
  }
  *(final+1) = 0;
  return string;
}

// splits row by commas and places them into the structs
char** customStrTok(char* line, int sortedColumnNum) {

    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    int k = 0;

    // stores resulting fields
    char** result = (char**)malloc(sizeof(char*) * (sortedColumnNum + 1));

    char* container = (char*)malloc(500);

    // checks for quotation marks in string
    int boolIsQuote = 0;

    //go through each character
    while(i < strlen(line)){

        if(line[i] == '"' && boolIsQuote == 0){
            boolIsQuote = 1;
        }

        else if(line[i] == '"' && boolIsQuote == 1){
            //store value in result
            result[k] = (char*) malloc((j + 1) * sizeof(char));
            container = removeWhitespace(container, j - 1);
            strcpy(result[k], container);
            memset(&container[0], 0, strlen(container));
            boolIsQuote = 0;
            j = 0;
            k++;
            i++;
        }

        //splits row by columns
        else if((line[i] == ',' || i == strlen(line) - 1) && boolIsQuote != 1){
            //if there is no character; (eg: ,,)
            if(!container){
                container[0] = '\0';
            }
            if(i == strlen(line) - 1 && line[i] != '\n'){
                container[j] = line[i];
                j++;
            }
            // copy into result array
            result[k] = (char*)malloc((j+1) * sizeof(char));
            container = removeWhitespace(container, j - 1);

            strcpy(result[k], container);

            memset(&container[0], 0, strlen(container));

            j = 0;
            k++;

            // if comma is at the end
            if(line[i] == ',' && i == strlen(line) - 2){

                container[0] = '\0';

                result[k] = (char*)malloc((j+1) * sizeof(char));

                strcpy(result[k], container);
                memset(&container[0], 0, strlen(container));
            }

        } else{

            //copy into container
            if(j == 0){
                if(line[i] == ' '){
                    i++;
                    continue;
                }
            }
            container[j] = line[i];
            j++;
        }
        i++;
    }
    i = 0;

    return result;
}

void beginSort(char* selectedColumn, char* fileName){

    printf("%s\n", "Begin sort called");

    FILE* fp;

    fp = fopen(fileName, "r");

        row titleRow;
        int sortedColumnNum = 1;
        char *token;

        // sets up the row of column titles

        titleRow.rowValue = (char*) malloc (sizeof(char) * 1000);



        printf("%s\n", "Program stops here when on forked process");
        printf("I failed. This is my id, %d, and this is my parents id %d\n", getpid(), getppid());
        fgets(titleRow.rowValue, 999, fp);
        printf("%s\n", "Got passed fgets");


        titleRow.rowLength = strlen(titleRow.rowValue);
        titleRow.fields = (char**) malloc(sizeof(char *) * titleRow.rowLength);



        token = strtok(titleRow.rowValue, ",");
        titleRow.fields[0] = token;

        //Beginning splitting the tokens and check if the column name entered exists
        int selectedColumnExist = 0;



        while((token = strtok(NULL, ","))){



            titleRow.fields[sortedColumnNum] = token;

            //This removes the last whitespace value (\n) because for the last column in the CSV, the check would fail
            titleRow.fields[sortedColumnNum] = removeWhitespace(titleRow.fields[sortedColumnNum], strlen(titleRow.fields[sortedColumnNum]) - 1);


            if (strcmp(titleRow.fields[sortedColumnNum], selectedColumn) == 0){
                //the column exists
                selectedColumnExist = 1;

            }

            sortedColumnNum++;
        }

        if (selectedColumnExist != 1){
            printf("Sorry, the column you entered doesn't exist in the csv\n");
            return;
        }

        titleRow.sortedColumnNum = sortedColumnNum;

        int length = strlen(titleRow.fields[sortedColumnNum - 1]);
        if(titleRow.fields[sortedColumnNum - 1][length - 1] == '\n'){
            titleRow.fields[sortedColumnNum - 1][length - 2] = '\0';
        }

        // trim column titles
        int i = 0;
        while(i < sortedColumnNum){
            titleRow.fields[i] = removeWhitespace(titleRow.fields[i], strlen(titleRow.fields[i]) - 1);
            i++;
        }

        row *data;
        int numberOfRows;
        data = (row*) malloc (sizeof(row) * 15000); //size matters


        // non title rows, aka all the other ones
        row regularRow;
        regularRow.rowValue = (char*) malloc (sizeof(char) * 1000);
        int currentRow = 0;

        while(fgets(regularRow.rowValue, 999, fp) != NULL){
            regularRow.rowLength = strlen(regularRow.rowValue);
            regularRow.fields = (char**) malloc(sizeof(char *) * (sortedColumnNum+1));
            regularRow.fields = customStrTok(regularRow.rowValue, sortedColumnNum);
            data[currentRow++] = regularRow;
        }

        numberOfRows = currentRow;

        int columnToSort = 0;

        while(columnToSort < titleRow.sortedColumnNum){
            if(strcmp(titleRow.fields[columnToSort], selectedColumn) == 0){
                break;
            }
            columnToSort++;
        }

        //Call mergesort

        mergeSort(data, columnToSort, numberOfRows);



        //Export to a new file

        FILE *fp2;
        char* filename2;

        //make this work
        //filename2= strcat(fileName, "-sorted-.csv");
filename2="result.csv";

        printf("%s\n", "Begin export");
        printf("%s\n", filename2);


        fp2=fopen(filename2,"w+");


        int vv,zz;
        vv = 0;

            while(vv < sortedColumnNum){

                fprintf(fp2, titleRow.fields[vv]);

                if(vv != sortedColumnNum - 1){
                    fprintf(fp2, ",");
                }else{
                    fprintf(fp2, "\n");
                }

                vv++;
            }

            vv = 0;
            zz = 0;

            while(vv < numberOfRows){

                while(zz < sortedColumnNum){

                    fprintf(fp2, data[vv].fields[zz]);

                    if(zz != sortedColumnNum - 1){
                        fprintf(fp2, ",");
                    }else{
                        fprintf(fp2, "\n");
                    }

                    zz++;
                }
                vv++;
                zz = 0;
            }

            fclose(fp2);


}

void traverseDirectory(char* dirName, char* selectedColumn){

    DIR *dir;
    struct dirent *ent;
    if ((dir = opendir (dirName)) != NULL) {
      /* print all the files and directories within directory */
      while ((ent = readdir (dir)) != NULL) {
          char* itemName = ent->d_name;
          int length = strlen(itemName);
         int pid;


         //CSV FILE FOUND
          if (length > 0 && itemName[length - 1] == 'v'
                  && itemName[length - 2] == 's'
                && itemName[length - 3] == 'c'
                && itemName[length - 4] == '.' )
{
              //confirm if valid csv file (opens correctly and has valid headers)
                            pid = fork();
                            printf("%d\n", pid);
                            printf("%s\n", "CSV found");


}


                        switch(pid){
                        case 0:

                        beginSort(itemName, selectedColumn);
                            break;


                        case -1:
                            printf("%s\n", "Error creating fork");

                        default:
                            continue;
                        }





                        return;



         // printf("%d\n", strlen(itemName));



        //printf ("%s\n", itemName);
      }
      closedir (dir);
    } else {
      /* could not open directory */
      perror ("");
      return;
    }

    //CODE TO OPEN DIRECTORY GIVEN GOES HERE
    /*
     * DIR* test = opendir(dirName);
     * dirent* newfile = readdir(test);
     *
     */


    /*for (loop to iterate through everything in given dirName){
         *

         if (DIRECTORY){

             pid = fork();

             switch(pid){
             case 0:
                traverseDirectory(directoryName);


             case -1:
             error

             default:
             continue;

         }

        if (FILE){
            if (currentFile == CSV && currentFile == validCSV file){

                pid == fork();

            }

            switch(pid){
            case 0:
            beginSort(currentfile, selectedColumn)
                break;


            case -1:
                error

            default:
                continue;
            }



            }

            return;
        }*/


}

int main (int argc, char* argv[]){

    // column to sort by
    char* selectedColumn;

    if (strcmp(argv[1],"-c") != 0){
                printf("Sorry, you must use the -c flag to declare a column\n");
                return 1;
        }

    if (argc != 3 && argc != 5 && argc != 7){
        printf("Invalid argument size\n");
                    return 1;
    }

    selectedColumn = argv[2];


    //beginSort(selectedColumn, "movie_metadata.csv");

    if (argc == 3){
        traverseDirectory("./", selectedColumn);
    }



    if (argc == 5){
        //check if argv[3] == -d
        //{ do something }

        //check if arv[3] == -o
        //{ do something }
    }

    if (argc == 7){
        //check if argv[3] == -d && argv[5] == -o
        //
    }



    return 0;
}
```

Anyone have any idea? The GDB seems to report the seg fault way before the line that the program actually fails on so I'm torn here.

Comment: A segfault in `strcmp()` likely means that either one or more of the strings being compared is not properly terminated, or that one or more of the string pointers is altogether invalid in the first place.

Comment: That the error does not manifest in the parent process does not mean that the functions are ok, it just means that the undefined behavior involved happens to manifest differently in that case.

Comment: @JohnBollinger How can I pinpoint which line or string it is? I tried reading the register values but the first one was 0 and the second one just had nonsensical data

Comment: was there not a stack trace when you get the segv? type `where` in gdb to see where in your code the failed `strcmp` happened and then you can go up and examine the variables you're passing in

Comment: @ChrisTurner Ah I didnt know about this command. This is what returned: 
#1  0x0000000000401d16 in main (argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffe318) at sorter.c:442 which is this line: if (strcmp(argv[1],"-c") != 0){ ......what does argv become in a forked process?

Comment: @Laugh7, Don't add info in the comments; add it to the question.

Comment: @Laugh7, you could start with gdb, when it catches the segfault, by looking back in the call stack to the frames that belong to your program's functions.  Examining the variables that are being passed should help you characterize the immediate problem.  It's fairly likely that the actual program flaw responsible for the (I presume) malformed values is elsewhere, but this will help you figure out where to look.

Comment: @ikegami updated main post

Comment: That line is called well before you even get as far as `fork`ing a new process. The stack trace shows the problem quite clearly - `argc=1` - you're not checking there are any arguments before trying to access `argv`

Comment: and your child process should `exit()` when it's done, otherwise it'll continue processing the directory looking for more CSV files

Comment: @ChrisTurner ah Im an idiot. I wasnt inputting my arguments in GDB. the argument is -c an director_name. updating main post now. main problem still exists

Answer (score 1):

So your code looks a bit like this...I've removed the lines that aren't related to the problem.

```
fp = fopen(fileName, "r");
// ....
fgets(titleRow.rowValue, 999, fp);
```

What happens in your code if `filename` doesn't exist? You should always check the return value of functions to make sure they've worked.

You're making the assumption that because `traverseDirectory` found the file, that you can open it. But you're forgetting that `itemName` is relative to `dirName`. You need to combine the two, to get the full filename for you to be able to open it.

There is also a problem with how you identify a CSV file.

```
if (length > 0 && itemName[length - 1] == 'v'
    && itemName[length - 2] == 's'
    && itemName[length - 3] == 'c'
    && itemName[length - 4] == '.' )
```

If `length` is 3 (for example), you'll end up accessing `itemName[-1]` which isn't right. You want to make sure that length is at least 5 (unless a file called ".csv" is valid?) and you could use `strcmp` to make it easier to see what you're doing too.

```
if (length > 4 && strcmp(itemName+length-4,".csv")==0)
```

Comment: Hahaha......found the error.....I'm an idiot. When I was calling beginSort(), the parameters were backwards...jeez. Thank you! Works now!